# Match all instances of a certain character inside every word preceded by a certain word and not delimited by a space

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, gsub

Given a string such as below:

word.hi. bla. word.

I want to construct a regex which will match all "."s preceded by "word" and any other non space character

So, in the above example I would want the the first, second and last dots to be matched.

While matching the first and last dots would be easy with global flag (/(?:word.*)\K./gU), I'm not sure how to construct a regex that would also match the second dot.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: I'm trying to use gsub in ruby, to substitute the dots out for dashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might match *word* and then get all consecutive matches using the `\G` anchor excluding matching whitespace chars or a dot.

```
(?:\bword|\G(?!\A))[^.\s]*\K\.
```

In parts

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bword` Match `word` preceded by a word boundary
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `[^.\s]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `.` or a whitespace char
- `\K` Clear the match buffer (forget what is matched until now)
- `\.` Match a dot

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/aITMIGqD4kczoM)

Comment: cool thanks, that works really well indeed, marked this as accepted answers though shouldn't the dot be escaped ? (i.e. in [^.\s])

Comment: @rmadhwal The `\G` anchor matches at 2 places, at the start of the string or at the end of the previous match. Using `(?!\A)` prevents the match at the start of the string as it should match after word. The dot inside the character class does not need to be escape.

Comment: just read how the \G works after I typed that so edited it out! Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: In hindsight, the [^.\s]* bit is quite clever indeed, props